# Can I use Python App Engine Memcache's cas (compare and set) when a value isn't yet cached?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

I want to cache the results of an ndb query in memcache.  When I do something that would cause the results to change, I delete the key to invalidate it.  When I need it, I check if it has been cached and, if not, I do the query and cache it.

However, there is a race condition.  Sample code is below:

```
def Invalidate():
  memcache.delete(KEY)

def GetFromCacheOrQuery():
  client = memcache.Client()
  if not client.get(KEY, for_cas=True):
    result = DoQuery() # This is slow, so it should be cached
    client.cas(KEY, result)
```

The race condition if I were to use client.set rather than client.cas:

1. Someone runs Invalidate.
2. GetFromCacheOrQuery stores DoQuery() in result
3. Someone runs Invalidate.  Now, the results from DoQuery are INVALID and SHOULD NOT be cached.
4. GetFromCacheOrQuery resumes, caching the result that is invalid.

I believe that cas solves the race condition, but cas never actually sets the value if the previous get returned None (which is the case if the value is deleted).

Is there a way to get around this?  Should I just store a custom value for invalidation rather than deleting the key, or is there a cleaner way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're describing the gumball solution described in excruciating detail here: http://abineshtd.blogspot.com/2012/09/gumball-race-condition-prevention.html

Yes, a good way to solve this problem is to store a value with a short timeout that means "this value is invalidated" and then don't overwrite it -- let it expire. This means caching won't work for a little bit, but that's better than getting bad data.